# What's the best unique identificator in pop3 with imap functions in php?

Tags: pop3

I have a question, What's the best unique identificator in imap with php? look, i'm working with a pop3 account, but the host deletes emails, every week automatically, so, they restart the `uid` and they turn it to 1. That's a problem, because I copy the Imap mails to MySQL database and when i update the database I have with UNIQUE attribute the field named `uid`, and it doesn't updates. I don't know if the best unique identificator is `message_id`.

Comment: Are you using IMAP or POP3?  They're not the same thing.

Comment: oh... sorry, i changed it now

Answer (score 0):

In IMAP, on a properly implemented server, the full unique ID for a message is based on a tuple made up of the (folder name, UIDVALIDITY, message UID).  If the folder is recreated, it should have a new UIDVALIDITY.

Comment: Well. but, in my case what should i do? If the UID restarts.

Comment: Store that tuple as your uid, not just the folder specific uid. Eg inbox:1484748992:5.

Comment: Oh, you're using pop3? The only identifiers you have are the UIDL identifiers.